# Как записать в файл результат парсинга на Python?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4, lxml

Нужно из страницы вытащить таблицу, которую по итогу буду парсить и положу в .csv файл.
Ниже код вытягивает нужную мне таблицу, а как мне результат выполнения записать в файл, чтобы мне с ним уже потом работать отдельно?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def open_file():
    html = open('table.html', encoding='utf-8').read()
    html_sorted = open('html_sorted.html', 'w+',encoding='utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='table')
    print(table)



open_file()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня есть HTML страница на компьютере с кучей ненужных мне данных. Я с помощью bs4 вытаскиваю нужные мне данные из тэга <table> class<table>.
Я хочу этот результат сохранить в отдельный .html документ и проводить дальнейшие операции уже с ним. Не могу понять с помощью каких инструментов это реализовать. Чтобы на компьютере рядом с исходным файлом появился еще один с результатом парсинга.

Comment: `html_sorted.write(table); html_sorted.close()` - как-то так по идее. Но лучше открывайте файлы с помощью `with`, чтобы не закрывать их вручную.

Comment: учебник - глава о том, как открыть, записать и закрыть файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
title = soup.find('div', class_='row') 
table = soup.find('table', class_='table') 
table = str(table) 
title = str(title) 
html_sorted.write(title + table) 
html.close() html_sorted.close()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).